# Evolution-ews: Ticket Expired. How to renew ticket after suspend?

Tags: suspend, evolution, ms-exchange

I connect Evolution to an MS Exchange Server. That works just fine. But when waking up from suspend, Evolution cannot connect anymore with Error Message "Ticket Expired".

[image: Ticket Expired]

That happens regardless if Evolution was closed or not during suspend, it does still occur after closing and reopening Evolution.

After a reboot the connection works again.

How can I either fix this issue OR just do a full restart of evolution (including the eventual backend services) without having to reboot ?

**Update:**

I tried `evolution -q` and `evolution --force-shutdown`, but it didn't help.

Running with `--gtk-debug=error`:

```
$ evolution --gtk-debug=error
(evolution:28353): Gtk-DEBUG: Connecting to session manager
(evolution:28353): Gtk-DEBUG: Registering client 'evolution' ''
(evolution:28353): Gtk-DEBUG: Registered client at '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Client25'

(evolution:28353): camel-WARNING **: Failed to initialize NSS SQL database in sql:/etc/pki/nssdb: NSS error -8126
```

The `Failed to initialize` - Warning is always there, also when everything works.

Comment: Please start `evolution --debug=evolution_error_log` in a terminal, reproduce the error and add the content of `evolution_error_log`  to your question using a  code block (`{}` button) or https://paste.ubuntu.com. Did you already try to close it using `evolution -q` and `evolution --force-shutdown`? What is the output of these commands?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try everything later today. Strange: Even that `man evolution` tells me `--debug=FILE` exists, it returns an error: `Unknown option --debug=evolution_error_log`.

Comment: That's really strange, I get the same behaviour – use `evolution --gtk-debug=error` instead, let's see whether this shows something useful… Btw. `evolution --help` doesn't list the `--debug` option. Did someone forget to update the manpage?

Comment: I filed a bug for this, please visit https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1718613 and click “This bug affects me”.

Comment: That's something! Did you see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459504/evolution-appears-unable-to-store-mail-account-details)?

Comment: I think it's a different bug, as my EWS Account works great. I don't want to delete account config ... But I tried deleting the cache folder, but it doesn't help. There are some processes left when not quitting with `--force-shutdown`. Using `kill $(pgrep ".*evolution.*")` doesn't help either.